# CSV import in Rails for a model with multiple associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, activerecord

Here I'm trying to import a CSV file to a table called `rankings` which has the following schema:

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| search_text    | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| first_item_id  | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| second_item_id | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| third_item_id  | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| forth_item_id  | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

`rankings` table has multiple associations to the `items` table which has the following schema :

```
+---------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                        | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| item_code                 | varchar(255) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+---------------------------+
```

Sample data `rankings`

```
+----+-------------+---------------+----------------+---------------+---------------+ 
| id | search_text | first_item_id | second_item_id | third_item_id | forth_item_id |
+----+-------------+---------------+----------------+---------------+---------------+
|  1 | test 1      |             1 |              2 |             3 |             4 |
|  2 | test 2      |             1 |              2 |             3 |             4 |
|  3 | test 3      |             1 |              2 |             3 |             4 |
|  4 | test 4      |             1 |              2 |             3 |             4 |
+----+-------------+---------------+----------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Sample data `items`

```
+--------+------------+
| id     | item_code  |
+--------+------------+
|      1 | 125659     |
|      2 | 125660     |
|      3 | 125661     |
|      4 | 125662     |
+--------+------------+
```

Model class for `rankings` table :

```
class Base::Ranking < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :first_item, foreign_key: :first_item_id, class_name: 'Item'
   belongs_to :second_item, foreign_key: :second_item_id, class_name: 'Item'
   belongs_to :third_item, foreign_key: :third_item_id, class_name: 'Item'
   belongs_to :forth_item, foreign_key: :forth_item_id, class_name: 'Item'
end
```

At this point I've developed to import a CSV which holds `items.id` for `first_item_id`, `second_item_id`, `third_item_id` and `forth_item_id` with exact same header names as the table using rails `import`. But preferably i should be able to change this approach to when CSV holds `items.item_code` data as well as headers are not exactly the table's fields.

The current code :

```
  def import_csv(file)
     begin
       ranking_records = []
       CSV.foreach(file.path, encoding: 'CP932:UTF-8', headers: true) do |row|
         ranking_records << row.to_h
       end
       Base::Ranking.import(ranking_records)
     rescue => e
       Rails.logger.error e.message
     end
     redirect_to(rankings_path)
   end
```

Existing CSV format :

[image: Existing-csv]

Updated CSV format :

[image: Updated-csv]

What would be the best approach to import to `rankings` from updated CSV format?

I did a workaround by loading the `items` to a hash and then within the loop I just persist to the `ranking` taking `items.id` from the hash. But seems like im not able to get from the hash as I intended to and I want to handle either `items.item_code` being `NULL` too. Any suggestions on this?

```
 def import_csv(file)
   begin
    all_items = Item.all.select(:id, :item_code)
    item_map = all_items.map{ |c| [c.item_code,c.id] }.to_h
    CSV.foreach(params[file.path, encoding: 'CP932:UTF-8', headers: false) do |row|

       ranking = Ranking.new
       ranking.search_text = item_map[row[0]]
       ranking.first_item_id = item_map[row[1]]
       ranking.second_item_id = item_map[row[2]]
       ranking.third_item_id = item_map[row[3]]
       ranking.forth_item_id = item_map[row[4]]
       ranking.save

    end
  rescue => e
     Rails.logger.error e.message
 end
 redirect_to(rankings_path)
end
```

Comment: The first thing you should do is to remove the logic of importing the file from the controller and put it into something like a service object where you can test it in isolation.  Then do some reasearch on `insert_all` (Rails 6+) or the ActiveRecord import gem for legacy apps.